# Why does SQL Server 2019 stored proc get Adaptive Join on Development Server, but not on Production Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, query-performance

I have a stored proc with one select statement that gets a plan w/ Adaptive Joins on my development server, but not on my production server.  What could explain that?  I'm not much interested in tuning advice, just in

1. what allows adaptive joins on one server, but not the other, and
2. what causes much slower performance on Prod from SSRS & Plan Explorer vs. quick execution on Prod from SSMS.

All of these results stay the same no matter how many times I execute the statement, w/ no change between the first execution & subsequent ones.

1. It finishes in 2 seconds from SSMS on both Dev & Prod servers.
2. On Dev Server it also finishes in 2 seconds from SQLSentry Plan Explorer & SSRS report
3. On Prod Server it finishes in ~60 seconds from SQLSentry Plan
   Explorer & SSRS report

The Dev database is restored from a Prod backup every night, then logging tables are dropped on Dev, files are shrunk on Dev, and Dev is backed up in case developers want to restore the .bak file to their local machine.

1. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkDLE9AQ9 - spWoFormsDescriptionFormIDSelect - DevServer - PlanExplorer - 2 seconds - Adaptive Join
2. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkIYLqAQ9 - spWoFormsDescriptionFormIDSelect - DevServer - SSMS - 2 seconds - Adaptive Join
3. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rknh89RQc - spWoFormsDescriptionFormIDSelect - ProdServer - PlanExplorer - 54 seconds - NO Adaptive Join
4. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1cyvcA7c - spWoFormsDescriptionFormIDSelect - ProdServer - SSMS - 2 seconds - NO Adaptive Join
5. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rknh89RQc - spWoFormsDescriptionFormIDSelect - ProdServer - SSRS - 60 seconds - NO Adaptive Join

PROD Server (from sp_Blitz)

1. Poison Wait Detected: RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE  - 0:21:22:29 of this wait have been recorded. This wait often indicates killer performance problems.
2. Memory Pressure Affecting Queries  - 9 forced grants reported in the DMV sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores, indicating memory pressure has affected query runtimes.
3. cost threshold for parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 5 and it has been set to 2000.
4. max degree of parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 3.
5. max server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 2147483647 and it has been set to 54784.
6. min server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 54784.
7. In-Memory OLTP (Hekaton) In Use  - 0% of your 53.50GB of your max server memory is being used for in-memory OLTP tables (Hekaton).
8. Non-Dynamic Memory  - Minimum Server Memory setting is the same as the Maximum (both set to 54784). This will not allow dynamic memory. Please revise memory settings
9. Snapshot Backups Occurring  - 28 snapshot-looking backups have occurred in the last two weeks, indicating that IO may be freezing up.
10. 1 - PWAIT_DIRECTLOGCONSUMER_GETNEXT  - 17181.6 hours of waits, 96.5 minutes average wait time per hour, 0.0% signal wait, 483784541 waiting tasks, 127.9 ms average wait time.
11. Hardware  - Logical processors: 16. Physical memory: 64GB.
12. Hardware - NUMA Config  - Node: 0 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 16 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 140
13. Instant File Initialization Enabled  - The service account has the Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks permission.
14. Operating System Version  - You're running Windows Server 2016 Standard, version 10.0

DEV Server (from sp_Blitz)

1. DBCC SHRINK% Ran Recently  - The user SYSTEM has run file shrinks 3 times between Apr  5 2022  4:31AM and Apr  7 2022  4:32AM. So, uh, are they trying to cause bad performance on purpose?
2. Many Plans for One Query  - 2160 plans are present for a single query in the plan cache - meaning we probably have parameterization issues.
3. One database has foreign keys that were probably disabled, data was changed, and then the key was enabled again.  Simply enabling the key is not enough for the optimizer to use this key - we have to alter the table using the WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT parameter.
4. TempDB Unevenly Sized Data Files tempdb - TempDB data files are not configured with the same size.  Unevenly sized tempdb data files will result in unevenly sized workloads.
5. backup compression default  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
6. cost threshold for parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 5 and it has been set to 1250.
7. max degree of parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 8.
8. max server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 2147483647 and it has been set to 109500.
9. min server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 109500.
10. In-Memory OLTP (Hekaton) In Use  - 0% of your 106.93GB of your max server memory is being used for in-memory OLTP tables (Hekaton).
11. Non-Dynamic Memory  - Minimum Server Memory setting is the same as the Maximum (both set to 109500). This will not allow dynamic memory. Please revise memory settings
12. Snapshot Backups Occurring  - 5 snapshot-looking backups have occurred in the last two weeks, indicating that IO may be freezing up.
13. SSAS/SSIS/SSRS Installed  - Did you know you have other SQL Server services installed on this box other than the engine? It can be a real performance pain.
14. No Significant Waits Detected  - This server might be just sitting around idle, or someone may have cleared wait stats recently.
15. Hardware  - Logical processors: 16. Physical memory: 128GB.
16. Hardware - NUMA Config  - Node: 0 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 16 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 215
17. Instance Stacking  - Your Server has 2 Instances of SQL Server installed. More than one is usually a bad idea. Read the URL for more info.
18. Instant File Initialization Enabled  - The service account has the Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks permission.
19. Operating System Version  - You're running Windows Server 2016 Standard, version 10.0

Thanks!

Comment: A couple guesses in lieu of a proper answer: your dev server is running developer edition, which is the equivalent of enterprise edition and can use the batch mode on row store feature. For the two slowest queries, it looks like ARITHABORT is set to off at the session level.

Comment: Developer Edition = Enterprise Features!  I was recently reminded of that, but it didn't sink in, or I blew it off b/c we don't have things like indexed views.  Thanks Erik!  I also suspected that SSRS & Plan Explorer must be doing something at the session level, but I didn't know which settings would be significant, so thanks for the ArithAbort tip!  I was disappointed with my question being too vague, but it was plenty for you!!  This query was inline in a SSRS rdl file to fill a parameter dropdown list.  I switched it to stored proc, which seems better, but we'll see how it does under load.